# Is it possible to pass parameters to html template in cartodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass certain value obtained using featureclick option to the customized infowindow template.

> ```
>    sublayer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data, layer) {
>      var hello=data.name;
>      alert("mouse clicked polygon with data: " + hello);
>       });
>        sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
> ```

```
      }).on('error', function() {
        console.log("some error occurred");
      });
```

I want to pass the value of the variable 'hello' to the info-window template. Is it possible?

Comment: Would like to learn more about this too. Were you able to find an answer Praveen?